# French Door Strike Box for Deadbolt - Too Short

Tags: doors, deadbolt

I just noticed my deadbolt on my french doors isn't fully engaging. There is a strike box inside the opposing door. It is a good 1/4" too shallow. I went to remove the strike box to see what I could do, but the strike box has some way of attaching that isn't normal screws. These little black circles will slide side to side and it looks like the hole goes all the way through to the back of the faster. Looks circular in there, so a hex key doesn't grab that I can tell.

[image]

So, looking to see what options I would have for making it fit, and also how to get the thing off?

Comment: The "slide side to side" portion allows for adjustment that direction. Can you get a _focused_ close up of the center of the two black screws? There's got to be a way to unscrew them, it might just be something you're not familiar with.

Comment: @FreeMan its a bit too dim outside right now to get one. I tried a flashlight on it but that made it worse I think. I'll try to grab one early tomorrow. Side note, the black things move freely side to side. they don't appear to be fastened to anything. the closest thing I can relate it to is the button on a pair of jeans. There is a wider piece through the oval that keeps it from falling out to the side I can see. But it isn't tight.

Comment: Those black things move _now_? That sounds rather odd...

Comment: @FreeMan Yes. They freely move side to side. Also, they are a somewhat soft plastic. Another commenter on a DIY forum said that is a box that a strike box/plate should go into. And those black things are for accepting the mounting screw on the box/plate.

Comment: That might be the case. Can you identify the brand? That might give us/you a clue.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was able to drill out the back though. So whatever those things are, they aren't a problem now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Self-answered questions are perfectly acceptable here. Please write up what you did down below in the "Your Answer" box to help others. Nothing more frustrating than finding someone else who had the same problem you have but finding that the only answer is ["never mind, I got it working"](https://xkcd.com/979/)...